# Max. Number of Search Results at Typefocus Blogger Template

Tags: html, search, hyperlink, blogger, blogspot

One of blogger template Typefocus and maybe some others has an important problem about max. search results they "found" in your site/blog.

When we make a search inside our blog like this (for example for word 'tanrı'):

> www.sonahit.com/search/?q=tanrı

we only see 20 results even if we have more posts in our blog that contains word "tanrı"...

even if we change max-result limit to more than 20, something like 40:

> [www.sonahit.com/search/?q=tanrı&max-results=40](http://sonahit.com/search/?q=tanr%C4%B1&max-results=40)

it already shows us 20 result

but if we make max-result limit lower than 20(for example to '1') it damn works!

> [www.sonahit.com/search/?q=tanrı&max-results=1](http://sonahit.com/search/?q=tanr%C4%B1&max-results=1)

it only shows us 1 result!

It's not limitiations about max. posts per page because if we want to see results start from 19th result:

> www.sonahit.com/search/?q=tanrı&max-results=40&start=19

it shows us only 2 result: (19th result) and (20th result) instead of showing 20 result per page...

I want to be able to **find** and **see** "all" -*not max. 20*- relevant results into my results page.

And some blogs(nearly all of them) shows us more than 20 results (posts) at multiple pages.

I want to remind you again, my problem isn't about showing results, it is about **finding** results...

Answer (score 0):

Standard search results in Blogger deliver at most 20 results and that's a behavior that is not possible to change, it's a server side constraint.

Consider using and customizing the inline "Search blog" **widget** or a **Custom Search Engine** provided by Google (you will have to include an extra piece of code in your template):

https://cse.google.com/cse/all